# Getting the Next Available Row

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

How can I get a List all the JobPositionNames having the lowest jobPositionId when ContactId = 1

### Tablel :

```
| JobPositionId | JobPositionName | JobDescriptionId | JobCategoryId | ContactId
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1        |  Audio Cables   |      1           |      1        |     1
       2        |Audio Connections|      2           |      1        |     1
       3        |Audio Connections|      2           |      1        |     0
       4        |Audio Connections|      2           |      1        |     0
       5        |   Sound Board   |      3           |      1        |     0
       6        |   Tent Pen      |      4           |      3        |     0
```

eg the result of this table should be lines 1,3,5,6

Comment: But `ContactId` is only 1 for row 1 in your example.

Comment: I want all the unique     JobPositionNames, (Audio Cables, Audio Connections, Sound Board, Tent Pen) and for the positions where there are more than one (2,3,4) I want the lowest     JobpositionId for when     Contactid = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out the solution.
Only lack of something, but I can give some code for you view.
Maybe it can help you.

```
--create table
create table t
(
JobPositionId int identity(1,1) primary key,
JobPositionName nvarchar(100) not null,
JobDescriptionId int,
JobCategoryId int,
ContactId int
)
go

--insert values
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('AudioCables', 1,1,1)
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('AudioConnections',2,1,1)
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('AudioConnections',2,1,0)
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('AudioConnections',2,1,0)
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SoundBoard',3,1,0)
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('TentPen',4,3,0)
COMMIT TRAN
GO

SELECT 
    Min(JobPositionId) AS JobPositionId, JobPositionName, ContactId
INTO
    #tempTable
FROM 
    t
GROUP BY JobPositionName, ContactId

SELECT * FROM #tempTable
WHERE JobPositionId IN (
    SELECT JobPositionId
    FROM #tempTable
    GROUP BY JobPositionName
    --... lack of sth, I can't figure out ,sorry.
)

drop table t
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

For per-group maximum/minimum queries you can use a null-self-join as well as strategies like subselects. This is generally faster in MySQL.

```
SELECT j0.JobPositionId, j0.JobPositionName, j0.ContactId
FROM Jobs AS j0
LEFT JOIN Jobs AS j1 ON j1.JobPositionName=j0.JobPositionName
AND (
    (j1.ContactId<>0)<(j0.ContactId<>0)
    OR ((j1.ContactId<>0)=(j0.ContactId<>0) AND j1.JobPositionId<j0.JobPositionId))
)
WHERE j1.JobPositionName IS NULL
```

This says, for each `JobPositionName`, find a row for which *there exists no other row* with a lower ordering value. The ordering value here is a composite [`ContactId`-non-zeroness, `JobPositionId`].

(Aside: shouldn't `JobPositionName` and `JobCategoryId` be normalised out into a table keyed on `JobDescriptionId`? And shouldn't unassigned `ContactId`s be `NULL`?)

Comment: Is this supposed to be an outer join? Is there some strange syntax for MySql that is making the JOIN up there outer?

Comment: oops, yes, you're right, I somehow forgot to type “LEFT”. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  jp.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  JobPositionName, JobPositionId, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    JobPosisions
        ) jpd
JOIN    JobPosisions jp
ON      jp.JobPositionId =
        IF(
        cnt = 1,
        jpd.JobPositionId,
        (
        SELECT  MIN(JobPositionId)
        FROM    JobPositions jpi
        WHERE   jpi.JobPositionName = jpd.JobPositionName
                AND jpi.ContactID = 0
        )
        )
```

Create an index on `(JobPositionName, ContactId, JobPositionId)` for this to work fast.

Note that if will not return the jobs having more than one position, neither of which has `ContactID = 0`